# MVC4 client side validation and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

**Answer:**

OK answer supplied below, by @www.innovacall.com is correct, I just didn't read it right the first time, now it works perfectly, thanks.

**Original question:**

I tried some solutions but none works for me.

In my project, I got a modal popup like this (I use bootstrap):

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="skillAnswerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">@ViewBag.AddressTimeTableMapModalEditHeaderTitle</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="addSkillAnswerModal">
            @Html.Partial("_AddSkillAnswer", Model.TempSkillAnswer)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">@ViewBag.CloseButtonLabel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddSkillAnswerModal" >@ViewBag.SaveChangesButtonLabel</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I submit data from that popup with the following ajax:

```
$("#btnAddSkillAnswerModal").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: addSkillUrl,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        traditional: true,
        data: $("#addSkillAnswerModal :input").serialize(),
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (result) {
            $("#skillAnswerModal").modal('toggle');
            $("#addSkillAnswerModal input[type!=hidden]").val('');
            $("#IsAnswerVisible").val("true");

            oTable.fnReloadAjax();
        }
    });
});
```

The problem:

Standard @Html.ValidationSummary() helper inside the View rendered in my modal popup, is not being called - thus I have no client side validation. I know that @Html.ValidationSummary() only works when I use @Html.BeginForm(...) but how can I validate my ajax before submit? I tried something like this:

```
$("#btnAddSkillAnswerModal").click(function () {
    $("#AddSkillAnswerForm").validate({
        debug: true,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                url: addSkillUrl,
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                traditional: true,
                data: $("#addSkillAnswerModal :input").serialize(),
                dataType: "json",

                success: function (result) {
                    $("#skillAnswerModal").modal('toggle');
                    $("#addSkillAnswerModal input[type!=hidden]").val('');
                    $("#IsAnswerVisible").val("true");

                    oTable.fnReloadAjax();
                }
            });
        },

        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            $("#summary").html("Your form contains "
            + this.numberOfInvalids()
            + " errors, see details below.");
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        }
    });
});
```

But it's not working, that is: there are no errors, but when I debug the JS, it sort of "skips" the validation, neither submitHandler nor showErrors is being hit...

How can I validate my form before ajax call?

Best regards.

EDIT1:

@www.innovacall.com:

I tried this approach but still it is not working for some reason...

My _AddSkillAnswer partial looks like this:

```
@model HostessServiceApplication.WebUI.Models.Admin.AgencyAnimatorSkillAnswerListAddSkillAnswer

@using HostessServiceApplication.Common.Localizer
@using HostessServiceApplication.WebUI.Resources
@using HostessServiceApplication.WebUI.Resources.Admin

@{
    Layout = null;

    //GlobalResources:
    var globalLocalizer = new UniversalTextLocalizer(typeof(TranslationStrings));
    ViewBag.SaveChangesButtonLabel = globalLocalizer.GetTranslatedVariable("SaveChangesButtonLabel");

    var viewSpecificLocalizer = new UniversalTextLocalizer(typeof(AddSkillAnswer));

    ViewBag.Title = viewSpecificLocalizer.GetTranslatedVariable("AddSkillAnswerPageTitle");
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddSkillAnswer", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" ,id="AddSkillAnswerForm"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    @Html.EditorForModel("Admin/AgencyAnimatorSkillAnswerListAddSkillAnswer")
}
```

I tried the following combinations:

```
$("#btnAddSkillAnswerModal").click(function () {
    var form = $("#AddSkillAnswerForm");

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
    //form.validate();
    form.validate({
        debug: true,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                url: addSkillUrl,
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                traditional: true,
                data: $("#addSkillAnswerModal :input").serialize(),
                dataType: "json",

                success: function (result) {
                    $("#skillAnswerModal").modal('toggle');
                    $("#addSkillAnswerModal input[type!=hidden]").val('');
                    $("#IsAnswerVisible").val("true");

                    oTable.fnReloadAjax();
                }
            });
        },

        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            $("#summary").html("Your form contains "
    + this.numberOfInvalids()
    + " errors, see details below.");
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        }
    });
});
```

and this:

```
$("#btnAddSkillAnswerModal").click(function () {
    var form = $("#AddSkillAnswerForm")
    .removeData("validator") /* added by the raw jquery.validate plugin */
    .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");  /* added by the jquery unobtrusive plugin */

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
    form.validate({
        debug: true,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                url: addSkillUrl,
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                traditional: true,
                data: $("#addSkillAnswerModal :input").serialize(),
                dataType: "json",

                success: function (result) {
                    $("#skillAnswerModal").modal('toggle');
                    $("#addSkillAnswerModal input[type!=hidden]").val('');
                    $("#IsAnswerVisible").val("true");

                    oTable.fnReloadAjax();
                }
            });
        },

        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            $("#summary").html("Your form contains "
    + this.numberOfInvalids()
    + " errors, see details below.");
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        }
    });
});
```

but still it doesn't work, neither submitHandler nor showErrors is being hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you loaded your form with ajax, you need to parse your form again :

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
form.validate();
if (form.valid()) {
    form.submit();
}
```